# How to get correct format on SQL calculations within SP

Tags: sql-server-2008, math, formula, calculated-columns

Beneath you can see some calculations i am  doing for my business within a big SP. I will just post a line of it here. The problem is that i cannot get the format right. It is supposed to be like this:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(30, 2), ( isa.sales_price * 0.8) * (1 - u.discount) ) as PRICE
```

Example of result:

- The isa.sales_price is: 149
- The u.discount is: 24
- The result is: -2741.60

What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT, here is the result after some help:**

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(30, 2), ( isa.sales_price * 0.8) * (1-(u.rabatt/100)) )
```

Comment: Your example values does not match what you expect in output, so something wrong there. But also - what datatype is your sales_price and your discount?

Comment: Edited. The sales_price is numeric and the discount is decimal. Both can be changed if its a better choice tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong - I suspect - is that the calculation isn't what you expect it to be:

149 * 0.8 * (1 - 24) does indeed return  -2741.60

Why do you expect it to give you something else?

If I were to venture a guess, you should divide discount with 100 as it's likely a percent value. But that's a guess.

Comment: Well yes that is true and im a little off today. While this is a formula in excel with 24 as a percentage it will return 90.592 which is what i am looking for. Since it is just a number in my DB it is returning the -2741.60 value. Anyone know how i can go around this and fix the formula to work?

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(30, 2), ( 149 * 0.8) * (1 - 24 / 100.0) )` returns 90.59 - as said in answer, I suspect you just need to divide discount with 100

Comment: True that, thanks :)
`CONVERT(DECIMAL(30, 2), ( isa.sales_price * 0.8) * (1-(u.rabatt/100)) )` this worked!